# How do you diff an entire repository in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Using the command line it's easy to do a graphic diff on your entire repository:

1. Navigate to anywhere in the repository.
2. Run `git diff`.

Assuming you have your tool configured correctly, this will go through all of the differences in your local branch file by file, line by line, and call your diff tool on each modified file in succession.

In Visual Studio 2015 I've found a way to do this one file at a time by using the "Compare with Unmodified..." option When you right-click a file in the Solution Explorer. But I have no idea how to do this for the entire repository at once, similar to the `git diff` command on the command line. Does any feature like this exist for Visual Studio 2015? And if so, how do I use it?

I am running Enterprise edition, although I'm hoping the version doesn't matter.